# Excel 2010: Set cell value to same value as other cell, even if cell is empty

Tags: excel, cell, defaultifempty

In Excel 2010, I want cell A1 to have the same value as cell A2. So I set a formula in A1:

```
=B1
```

that works fine if B1 has a value. But, if B1 is empty, then A1 shows "0". I want A1 to be empty if B1 is empty.

As a workaround, I'm using the following formula in A1:

```
=IF(B1="", "", B1)
```

Is there an easier and more elegant way to set a cell to the same value as other cell? (without VBA)

Comment: Whats wrong with `=IF(B1="", "", B1)` ? Works fine right?

Comment: @Bathsheba's got a fine answer though

Answer (score 3):

That's the way Excel works I'm afraid. `=B1` will display a zero if `B1` is empty. Futhermore `ISNNUMBER(B1)` will return `True`. So it is a genuine zero, not something formatted as a zero.

A common workaround is to use something like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1), "", B1)
```

which, I think, is more elegant than an empty string comparison.

Comment: Well it is very similar to me. I was thinking in something simpler, such as "=COPY(B1)", or even "==B1".

Answer (score 0):

Google spreadsheet works exactly as you need. Using

```
=A1
```

in B1, you get the desired empty B1 when A1 is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Under Excel Options > Advanced > Display options for this worksheet, is a tick box called 'Show a Zero in Cells that have zero value'. If you un-tick it then your formula will display blank if they result in zero. Only downside is that all cells that have a zero value (not from a formula) will also display blank.